# I'm trying to pass a PHP $_SESSION variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

So my ultimate goal is for my database to inform my site when something is sold so that it will darken out and so a hypothetical customer couldn't buy something that was already sold. I have the my database setting php session variables but I'm having trouble transferring that information into javascript/jquery. I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing it wrong or because there is something logically wrong with my approach. Thank you! Here is my code:
PHP:

```
<?php
$customer = new order;
$customer->item1Avail();
$customer->item2Avail();
$customer->item3Avail();
$customer->item4Avail();
var_dump($_SESSION);

$item1Status = $_SESSION['item1'];
$item2Status = $_SESSION['item2'];
$item3Status = $_SESSION['item3'];
$item4Status = $_SESSION['item4'];


?>
```

Jquery:

```
var item1Status = <?php echo json_encode($item1Status); ?>;
var item2Status = <?php echo json_encode($item2Status); ?>;
var item3Status = <?php echo json_encode($item3Status); ?>;
var item4Status = <?php echo json_encode($item4Status); ?>;


if(item1Status == "sold"){
$("#picture1").css("opacity", "0.5");
$("#button1").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#item1").css("opacity", "0.5"); 
} 

if(item2Status == "sold"){
$("#picture2").css("opacity", "0.5");
$("#button2").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#item2").css("opacity", "0.5"); 
} 

if(item3Status == "sold"){
$("#picture3").css("opacity", "0.5");
$("#button3").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#item3").css("opacity", "0.5"); 
} 

if(item4Status == "sold"){
$("#picture4").css("opacity", "0.5");
$("#button4").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#item4").css("opacity", "0.5"); 
}
```

Comment: `var item1Status = "<?php echo json_encode($item1Status); ?>";`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing logically wrong, you just need to wrap those php echos with quotes:

```
var item1Status = "<?php echo json_encode($item1Status); ?>";
var item2Status = "<?php echo json_encode($item2Status); ?>";
var item3Status = "<?php echo json_encode($item3Status); ?>";
var item4Status = "<?php echo json_encode($item4Status); ?>";
```

Comment: Not actually true.  You don't need quotes, AND at least part of the issue is that  the JSON does not get parsed before evaluated.  Why bother json_encoding if you aren't going to $.parseJSON, but attempt to access directly?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why I'm using json. I'm tried just echoing and ran into the same issue. Also tried with the quotes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: I'm checking it in firebug and the js variables seem to be being set. The css effect I set in the jquery still isn't happening. Am I somehow writing that part wrong?

Comment: The structure you're using seems to be fine: $("selector").css("property", "value"); Make sure you're entering those if statements and that you're using #id/.class correctly on the selector